# How do apps like Strava continue running in the background on the iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Just wondering if anyone knows how Strava is able to run in the background on iOS during workouts? I am currently building a location based iOS app that needs to continue running in the background, and I'm a little bit confused.

Over the past month I was able to whip up a prototype for the Apple Watch using HealthKit and HKLiveWorkoutBuilder, but it appears that I won't be able to use the same approach on the iPhone because many of the classes that I used on the watch aren't available on the phone such as HKWorkoutSession and HKLiveWorkoutBuilder.

Comment: They just use background location mode don't they?

Comment: Did Kurt's answer below give you what you need topherPederson? Do you know if the details are still relevant. It has been quite some time since this answer was published, but many of us are still working through this same problem.

Answer (score 1):

These applications generally utilize UIBackgroundModes capabilities in order to do any processing when the application is backgrounded. In particular, the background mode that is being used by Strava is most likely Background Location Services. It should be noted that Apple controls most of the resources/time allocated to your program and once it leaves the foreground it doesn't get these resources as freely as when its running in the foreground.

I've had the opportunity to work on a location services based application that required tracking and sending location updates even when backgrounded and was able to achieve this on iOS 8.

In recent years Apple have updated the way location services are requested from the user. The developer of the application can specify either requestAlwaysAuthorization or requestWhenInUse. The former will allow you to respond to location updates even when the application is backgrounded.

The CoreLocation API is pretty flexible e.g. you can specify whether you'd like to respond to only smaller changes in distance or larger ones.

The developer documentation is a pretty solid reference and if you'd like to find out more about background execution modes you can do so here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

To get you started with CoreLocation the following is good resource:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html

Comment: Thank you so much for the help Kurt! I was trying to do everything through HealthKit, but it looks like "Standard Location Service" is what I'm going to need on iOS.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer Kurt. Do we know if this answer is still up to date? I could use some help with this problem myself.